# Insertion sort Numerical

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, computer-science

I have two Arrays 1 with strings and another one with ints.
I have to use insertion sorts to print this list in acceding order numerical wise this is my code so far

these are the arrays:

```
String[]bn={"Cardinals","BlueJays","Albatross","Vultures","Crows","Mockingbirds","Condors","BaldEagles","Pigeons","RedHeadWoodPecker","Hummingbirds","Dodos"};


int[]bq={40,15,1,3,10,2,12,25,7,6,88,15};   

    public static void SortNumericalOrdernsert (String[] bn,int[] bq){
    for(int i=1;i<bq.length;i++){
        int next=bq[i];
        String y=bn[i];
        //find all the insertion location 
        //Move all the larger elements up
        int j=i;
        while(j>0 && bq[j-1]>next){
            bn[j]=bn[j-1];
            bq[j]=bq[j-1];
               j--;
        }
        //insert the element
        bq[j]=next;
        bn[j]=y;
    }

}}
```

Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: what do you mean with "have to"? Is this homework?

Comment: What problem are you having? Incorrect results? Crash? Compile error?

Answer (score 0):

// edited

You want to do like this?

```
public static void SortNumericalOrdernsert(String[] bn, int[] bq) {
    for (int i = 1; i < bq.length; i++) {
        int next = bq[i];
        // find all the insertion location
        // Move all the larger elements up
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && bq[j - 1] > next) {
            bq[j] = bq[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        bq[j] = next;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < bn.length; i++) {

        String y = bn[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && isBigger(bn[j - 1], y)) {
            bn[j] = bn[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        bn[j] = y;
    }
}

private static boolean isBigger(String left, String right) {
    return left.compareTo(right) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Well your code is sorting them alphabetically,it need to sort numerically.

Comment: The out has to be: 1,2,3,6,7,10,12,15,15,40,88

Comment: There was a bug.. Sorry I did not check the code. Is this what you want?